# anonymous functions/recursion in c#

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, anonymous-function, fibonacci

Can anyone please explain the behavior of this piece of code(from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx). I have not understood why does it display 18 for the last call.

```
Func<int, int> fib = null;
fib = n => n > 1 ? fib( n - 1 ) + fib( n - 2 ) : n;
Func<int, int> fibCopy = fib;
Console.WriteLine( fib( 6 ) );                        // displays 8
Console.WriteLine( fibCopy( 6 ) );                    // displays 8
fib = n => n * 2;
Console.WriteLine( fib( 6 ) );                        // displays 12
Console.WriteLine( fibCopy( 6 ) );                    // displays 18
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `fibCopy` still points to the original definition of `fib`: `n => n > 1 ? fib( n - 1 ) + fib( n - 2 ) : n;`. In that definition, `fib` is used. But `fib` has been changed to `n => n * 2`.

Executing `fibCopy(6)` will execute the following:

```
6 > 1 ? ((6-1) * 2) + ((6-2) * 2) : 6;
```

Because 6 is greater than 1, the first branch of the ternary expression will be evaluated:

```
(6-1) * 2 = 10
(6-2) * 2 =  8
           ---
            18
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That is a gud explanation.